# Suitescript -- Unexpected error on using getSelectOptions

Tags: php, netsuite, guzzle, suitescript

I'm trying to retrieve available options for shipping method for sales order form but I encountered an unexpected error in using getSelectOptions.

```
function get_select_options(datain)
{
    var rec = nlapiCreateRecord(datain.recordType);    
    var field = rec.getField(datain.field);
    var options = field.getSelectOptions();

    return options;
}
```

And here's my code for calling the script.

```
$url = "https://rest.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl";
$client = new Client();

$authorization = [
    'NLAuth nlauth_account='.getenv('NETSUITE_ACCOUNT'),
    'nlauth_email='.getenv('NETSUITE_EMAIL'),
    'nlauth_signature='.getenv('NETSUITE_PASSWORD'),
    'nlauth_role='.getenv('NETSUITE_ROLE')
];

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, 
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => implode(',', $authorization),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'query' => [
        'script' => '343',
        'deploy' => '1',
        'recordType' => 'salesorder',
        'field' => 'shipmethod'
    ]
]);

return json_decode($response->getBody());
```

My record type and field seems to be correct as what I have read in the docs. I also followed some of the example codes that uses getSelectOptions, but I can't move on because of some unexpected/unknown error. I also tried to return only the record (rec) just to make sure that my PHP code is working.

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException with message 
'Server error: `GET https://rest.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=343&deploy=1&recordType=salesorder&field=shipmethod` 
resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: 
{"error" : {"code" : "UNEXPECTED_ERROR", "message" : "An unexpected error has occurred. Error ID: irc3j6d915k2asvrqbfhb" (truncated...) '
```

Comment: The email you receive for these errors generally point in the direction of the problem and some inference may be required to identify the issue.

Comment: @spectre-d

"Account: XXXXXXX
Environment: SandBox
Date & Time: 8/2/2016 3:37 pm
Execution Time: 0.38s
Script Usage: 10
Script: SampleRestlet
Type: RESTlet
Function: get_select_options
Error: UNEXPECTED_ERROR
Ticket: ird19o9hcmemdbpfhdyu"

That's the email I received, just recently replicated the error.